# dissassemble .o file with fixups

Tags: assembly, objdump

I have tried

```
objdump -d myfile.o > myfile.lis
```

The output generated has zeroes wherever there is a link time or load time "fixup" in the compiled code.  For example one line of the output is:

```
1ab5:   0f 57 2d 00 00 00 00    xorps  0x0(%rip),%xmm5
```

That 0x0(%rip) is really a reference to some constant in the same .o file, but the disassembly gives me no hint of which one.
Another line is

```
1934:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1939 <garbage>
```

That is even more frustrating.  It is really a call to a named function in another module.  That function is not at offset 1939 of the current module (as the disassembly shows) and is not the giant garbage representation of offset 1939 that objdump produces, which I replaced with the word garbage when copying.

Is there another tool or another way of using objdump that will use the information from other parts of the same .o file to give correct disassembly for such lines in the .o file?  Or have I somehow installed a wrong version of objdump (relative to the compiler that produced the .o file) and a correct version of objdump would just work?

**Edit** in response to comments by stakx, I redid the test with a trivial file tiny.c containing

```
void tiny() { fun(0); }
```

and compiled with

```
gcc -c tiny.c
```

Then

```
objdump -d tiny.o
```

produces

```
0000000000000000 <tiny>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
   9:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   e:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  13 <tiny+0x13>
  13:   c9                      leaveq 
  14:   c3                      retq
```

That is exactly the same problem as seen in the more complicated example (the fixup is ignored in disassembling the call to foo).

Comment: I find it slightly difficult to judge/understand this question fully because so little about your setup is known. Could you perhaps post a (minimally complete) code example (`myfile.as`?), along with how you invoke the assembler (GNU `as`?) and perhaps a hint what CPU architecture you're dealing with?

Comment: I especially don't understand that "garbage". What would follow after the `callq` instruction in your original source code? What does the garbage look like, as output by `objdump`?

Comment: This should definitely be possible; all the information is there. As far as I know, GNU `objdump` can display fixup information on other architectures, like ARM.

Comment: I compiled C++ code with the Intel C++ compiler.  The function is a complicated template instantiation, causing the "garbage" when objdump tries to demangle the symbolic form of the **wrong** address.  That "garbage" is not the focus of my question.  The wrong address is.  I did not suspect the templating nor compiler as a factor in objdump's failure to include any contribution from fixups.  I thought objdump was the wrong tool or I was misusing it, so someone would tell me the correct command.  But maybe I need a simpler test to see if objdump ever disassembles with fixup contributions.

Comment: I edited the question to show the simpler test.  The problem occurs in a simple .c module compiled with gcc.  It does not depend on the Intel compiler, C++, templating or any of the other original complexities.  I also separately tested that the same behavior occurs in 32-bit x86.  So I still have my original assumption and question:  The objdump command I'm using does not include fixups in disassembly.  Is there some command or tool which does?

Comment: That's how objdump works on x86 targets. Short of fixing the code yourself there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Couldn't you just use objdump's `-r` option to display the relocation information along with disassembled code? So run `objdump -r -d tiny.o`